# Apache http server port change issue

Tags: apache, port

OS: Windows 7

I need to use Apache http server. For the same I downloaded it from Apache lounge. Now, after extracting the Apache24 folder to `C:\`, if I try to execute httpd.exe command from the bin folder, its giving me the OS 10013 error:

> (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>   (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

To resolve the same, I modified http.conf file for the following scenario:

a) Changed LISTEN 80 to "LISTEN 8080": Result: again executing the httd.exe command doesn't do anything at all. The command prompt simply sits idle

b) Added "LISTEN 8080" below to LISTEN 80 statement: Result: Again gives back the above OS 10013 error

c) in addition to case b, I also uncommented the servername entry in httpd.conf and made it like: "ServerName localhost:80" : Result: still the same OS 10013 error pops up.

Comment: Is it working if your choose an arbitrary port like 4521 ? If yes these port may be reserved, look at this question : http://superuser.com/questions/556759/tcp-udp-ports-that-cannot-be-bound-permission-error-but-dont-show-up-in-nets

Comment: Change it to say `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` or whatever port you want instead of **80**

Comment: Does your user have rights to create sockets (firewall)?

Comment: - Arbitrary port change didnt work

Comment: - Changed to Listen 127.0.0.1: 8080, that too didn;t work :(

Comment: Check the permissions and ownership of the folder and make sure the user under which `apache` runs has *read/write* permissions